# Getting updates with the Twilio CallStatus changes

Tags: twilio

I can't figure out how to tell when a Twilio call changes its CallStatus.  I know about the StatusCallback (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#asynchronous) but it only seems to fire when the call ends.  Is there any callback that will fire when the state changes to any of the states here?: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/what-do-the-call-statuses-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

I'm afraid that there is no explicit way of doing this. However, when Twilio makes an initial request for you TwiML, the call status will typically have changed from `queued` or `ringing` to `in-progress`. Then the Status callback will be fired when the call goes from `in-progress` to `completed`.

The callback should also be fired on `busy`, `no-answer`, `canceled` and `failed`.

So while there is not an explicit callback, you should pretty much know what is happening from the flow of you application.

Is there something specific you're trying to do that you can't with the above? Happy to help!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I'm attempting to make a call using the .net REST api. I do something like mycall = twil.initiateoutboundcall(options); then i do something based off mycall.status ; however i have noticed that sometimes status string has no value. Do you have any input on this? Other times it returns queued.  No call shows in the twilio logs.